# Default Web Browser is showing blank in eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, browser

I am using Eclipse Kepler for developing a web application that uses Apache server. My application runs fine when loaded on other browsers, however eclipse default browser shows blank page when loaded. I have checked the setting and selected option for default browser as `Internal Web Browser`.

I want to use default internal browser of eclipse to view my page. How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to configure it under window-> preferences. Then you need to set the run configuration to use the built in web browser. I got it working once but do not remember how to in more detail. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, can anybody give me more details.